# How do I get the taxonomy term's path alias?

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have come up with a need to show a node term's ***URL alias*** using plain php in drupal 8 but I can't figure out how to do it.
In my custom module, I want to get **/fruits/apples** in a variable upon loading ***a node*** which is linked with **Fruits** term.

Here you can see the Edit Term settings page in which I have set the URL alias of the term Fruits to /fruits/apples. I want to get this URL alias whenever a user loads a page linked to this term.

[image: term url alias]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do but have a look at ```$path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->load([
      'source' => '/' . $node->urlInfo()->getInternalPath(),
      'langcode' => $langcode    ]);```

Comment: @IvanJaros I want to get the URL alias of the term. The picture shows the Edit Term Page in which you can see the URL alias assigned to the term Fruits.

Comment: @IvanJaros I have updated the question with some more details.

Comment: But why is the path necessary on a node form? When the terms display on a node page, they’ll be linked.

Answer (score 10):

You can get it by this way as well (assuming you know $id in advance in code) as of Drupal 8.5.x:
**1. For taxonomy term:**

```
Term::load($id); //not important
$aliasManager = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
$alias = $aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/taxonomy/term/'.$id);
```

**2. For node:**

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($id); //not important
$aliasManager = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
$alias = $aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$id);
```

**OUTPUT:**
`$alias = /fruits/apples`

**EDIT:**
As of Drupal 8.8.x, `path.alias_manager` has been deprecated, use `path_alias.manager` in future versions of Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One thing that helps is to use code formatting on code blocks. You can do this manually by indenting the code or highlight all the code and click the code button (looks like curly braces: `{ }`).

Comment: This has been deprecated, per https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086.

Comment: Service name now is 'path_alias.manager', not 'path.alias_manager'.

Answer (score 3):

More right, easy and universal way:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($id);
$node_alias = $node->get('path')->alias;
```

You can also do extra checks if you are not sure if an alias exists:

```
if (!$node->get('path')->isEmpty()) {
    $node_alias = $node->get('path')->alias;
}
```

**UPDATED**

This will work for any entity type. But here is example for taxonomy terms:

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
if (!$term->get('path')->isEmpty()) {
    $term_alias = $term->get('path')->alias;
}
```

Comment: The questions asks for a taxonomy term path alias. Your answer is for a node path alias.

Comment: @John Thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer regarding this.